# Unable to locate element with relative XPATH or CSS selector, but absolute XPATH is located and clickable in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I'm struggling with locating an element to click. Here's what I am working with:

[image]

I'm trying to locate the element with the a href link. I've tried the following:

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'a[href="/collections/e-coated-kettlebells/products/28kg-kettlebell"]').click()

driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//div//a[@href="/collections/e-coated-kettlebells/products/28kg-kettlebell"]').click()

driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//a[@href="/collections/e-coated-kettlebells/products/28kg-kettlebell"]parent::div').click()
```

The absolute XPATH is the only thing that works

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="shopify-section-collection-template"]/div/div/div/div[25]/a').click()
```

The a href contains the 28kg element that I need to use. What am I missing in writing this CSS / XPATH?

Thanks!

[enter link description here](https://us.greatlakesgirya.com/collections/shop-kettlebells)

Is the website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are unique locators for that element.
XPath:

```py
"//div/a[contains(@href,'28kg-kettlebell')]"
```

CSS Selector:

```py
"div>a[href*='28kg-kettlebell']"
```

Inside Selenium methods it can be as following:
XPath:

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div/a[contains(@href,'28kg-kettlebell')]").click()
```

CSS Selector:

```py
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div>a[href*='28kg-kettlebell']").click()
```

Comment: You are more than welcome!

Comment: could you help me understand why? The div> adds the parent level? What is the asterisk adding?

Comment: `div` is the parent element. `>` direct child. The `a` element we need is a direct child of some `div`. `*=` means contains. href content is long enough, but `28kg-kettlebell` part of it is unique enough

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thank you so much! I've been able to learn so much about XPATHs and CSS selectors from stack, it's been super helpful

Comment: This is exactly what this platform for 